# Checking generic type

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

The Java Collections interfaces (for example, `List` or `Set`) define the `contains` method to accept any Object.

```
 public boolean contains(Object o)
```

However, when it comes to implementing this method, the particular collection I'm working on requires that I have a type which is compatible with the generic type `E` of the class (i.e. either be class E, or a subclass of E, or a class which implements E if E is an interface). In other words, if o is castable to type E, then it is compatible. This presents an issue because Java erases the Generic type information, so something like this isn't possible:

```
public boolean contains(Object o)
{
    if(o instanceof E) // compile error due to type erasures
    {
        // ... check if this collection contains o
    }
    return false;
}
```

My question is what would be the best way to accomplish something like this? The [Oracle Article on Type Erasures](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) mentions that this forbidden, but does not offer any solutions to this problem.

I can only think of one semi-elegant way to get around this:

Make a cast to type E. If the cast fails, o cannot be type E or a subclass of type E.

```
public boolean contains(Object o)
{
    try
    {
        E key = (E) o; // I know it's unsafe, but if o is castable to E then the method should work
        // check if this collection contains key
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
        // invalid type, cannot contain o
    }
    return false;
}
```

While this would work, it looks messy (I'm not a big fan of using Exceptions in this manner).

Is there a better way to accomplish this same goal (changing the method signature is not allowed)?

edit: yeah, this doesn't work because E gets erased to Object :(

Comment: Does it work? You'll get an unchecked cast compiler warning. You'll never get a ClassCastException (unless `o` is not an instance of `E`'s **erasure**, which is probably `Object`).

Comment: Can you elaborate on "requires that I have a type which is compatible with the generic type E of the class?"  Thanks.

Comment: I agree -- this would not work. You do need actual Class<E> to do proper cast that could fail.

Comment: If o meets the requirements of being compatible with E (added that info), then it must be cast-able to E. Yeah, I just tried it and you're right that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only possible by (1) passing in the expected `Class`, or (2) examining the generic type parameters of some reflective element that defines `<E>`.  Let me elaborate.

The most common case is to simply require the caller to pass in the runtime class of `E`.

```
public class MyClass<E> {
    private final Class<E> realType;
    public MyClass(Class<E> realType) {
        this.realType = realType;
    }
    public boolean Contains(Object o) {
        E e = realType.cast(o); // runtime cast - will throw ClassCastException.
        // Could also use realType.isInstance(o)
        // or realType.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())
        ...
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
new MyClass<MyObject>(MyObject.class)
```

This is generally type safe since the compiler will verify that the `<E>`'s match.  Of course the caller can bypass the compiler's checks...nothing you can do about that!

For (2), what I mean is that you can use reflection to examine *static* generic type parameters.  This probably isn't a good option in your case because you must have access to some field, method, or superclass declaration that statically defines `<E>`.  The most common way is to make your class abstract and have callers extend it.  This approach is used by Hamcrest's [TypeSafeMatcher](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.java?r=379) (see [ReflectiveTypeFinder](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/internal/ReflectiveTypeFinder.java?r=379)) to great effect.  (Note that TypeSafeMatcher is basically just making option (1) easier for the programmer; it still provides a constructor that takes the Class for cases when reflection doesn't work!)  If you want to get really fancy, you can inspect `getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getActualTypeArguments()`.  This isn't as easy as it sounds -- see [this good article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860).  I'm not even sure that article covers all the edge cases -- you're basically reimplementing the compiler!  So just go with option (1) and be happy you're not using generics in C# :-)

Comment: what's the point of generics if you're setting the type manually like this?

Comment: Generics still cleans up your source code by eliminating most casts and improving compiler type checking. Not defending Java's decision to use type erasure, but .NET generics have downsides too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get why you are messing with `.contains()` in this way. The specification of `contains()` in `Collection` says that it returns true if the given object equals (in the sense of `.equals()`) some element of the container. So are you changing the meaning of `.contains()`? How is your equality defined?

Comment: The Java TreeSet class doesn't use the equals() method to define equality (instead it uses the compareTo() method, or a Comparator). Trying to pass any object which can't be cast to the generic parameter of that TreeSet is a ClassCastException (which is part of the Javadoc for the contains() method). I have a similar situation with a different type of tree-like data-structure. Funny enough, the Javadoc does say that it use the equals() method for contains().

Comment: @helloworld922: "Trying to pass any object which can't be cast to the generic parameter of that TreeSet is a ClassCastException" That's not true. There's no such thing as generic parameters at runtime. All a TreeSet does with an object at runtime is cast it to Comparable, and then use "compareTo" to compare it with other objects. A ClassCastException only occurs if the objects you are putting in are not comparable to each other.

Comment: Ah, true. I'm use to having Comparable objects usually comparable to themselves, but you're right that that does not need to be true.